# show month / day / year - not works

Tags: php

It is such that I must have set day and month and year, but this is how I have problems with it here:

how the problem looks like now. (The problem is that there is going to be "array ...." before the day and date, and year.)
"ArrayTirsdag 11 Jun 2013"

Would like this:
"Tirsdag 11 Jun 2013"

```
echo "<td>" . 
                $days = array("Mandag","Tirsdag", "Onsdag","Torsdag","Fredag","Lørdag","Søndag");
                $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec");
                $timestamp = strtotime($c->pubDate);
                $dayInWeek = $days[date('N', $timestamp)-1];
                $month = $months[date('n', $timestamp)-1];
                $dayInMonth = date('d', $timestamp);
                $year = date('Y', $timestamp);
                echo $dayInWeek . ' ' .$dayInMonth. ' '.$month.' '.$year
                . "</td>";
```

Comment: You should `var_dump` your `$dayInWeek` variable to see the contents. Based on your output, it looks like `$dayInWeek` is literally an array at the time of the `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have a `.` when you need a `;` so instead of echoing `<td>` you're trying to echo all of your logic. So change the first line to `echo "<td>";` and you're set.  You might as well save the opening `<td>` for the end too like this:

```
// date logic
$days       = array("Mandag", "Tirsdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lørdag", "Søndag");
$months     = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec");
$timestamp  = strtotime($c->pubDate);
$dayInWeek  = $days[date('N', $timestamp)-1];
$month      = $months[date('n', $timestamp)-1];
$dayInMonth = date('d', $timestamp);
$year       = date('Y', $timestamp);

echo "<td>$dayInWeek $dayInMonth $month $year</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have . instead of comma on first echo.

```
echo "<td>"; 
                $days = array(1=>"Mandag","Tirsdag", "Onsdag","Torsdag","Fredag","Lørdag","Søndag");
                $months = array(1=>"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec");
                $timestamp = strtotime($c->pubDate);
                $dayInWeek = $days[date('N', $timestamp)];
                $month = $months[date('n', $timestamp)];
                $dayInMonth = date('d', $timestamp);
                $year = date('Y', $timestamp);
                echo $dayInWeek . ' ' .$dayInMonth. ' '.$month.' '.$year
              . "</td>";
```